# How do i get the value of a method to use in main

Tags: java, methods, return, program-entry-point

i'm still pretty new with Java and am trying to write a program that will show me how much my money is actually getting me whenever i make an ingame purchase.
I'm struggling with getting the value from the method convertYourself() into my main method so that i can combine them.
I think i would most likely need make it a double instead of a void and return it but what would i pass as the parameter?
Thank you!

```
public class TestCode {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static double gemValue = 0.01;
    public static double goldValue = 0.000004;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestCode test = new TestCode();
        test.convertYourself(gemValue);
        test.convertYourself(goldValue);
        // double sum = how do i get the value of the convertYourself method so i can use it here?
        System.out.println("The total value of this bundle is :" + sum);
    }

    public void convertYourself(double x) {
        System.out.println("How many are you buying?");
        double currency = in.nextDouble();
        double convert = currency * x;
        System.out.println("The true value of this is: " + convert);
        

    }

}
```

Comment: [The Java™ Tutorials - Returning a Value from a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Comment: methods have no values, they can return values, yours doesn't return anything. either store the value in an (instance) variable, or have it return a value

Comment: Also it is not advisable to have your `Scanner` declared in the class itself. Rather declare and use it inside the function

Comment: @ram why would that be advisable? It's a terrible idea to instantiate a new one each time you call the method

Comment: @Stultuske so is having the Scanner in the class correct or should i put it inside the method itself?

Comment: @Decline there is no problem with having it as a class member. It might even be better if you declare it static, since you always will want the terminal for input. This would mean you won't create a new one for each instance

Comment: @Stultuske This class has just a main function. In other cases, you don't want a Scanner object to get instantiated whenever an object of that class is created. Also, for each time it gets instantiated in the function, it also does get deleted from the memory when the function ends and control is returned to the main. It is more memory efficient doing that way :)

Comment: @ram "this class has just a main function". Nope. it has an instance method, and that's where the Scanner is being used.  now it's just one method. What if it are ten methods, all with a scanner? Are you going to duplicate code just for some "additional efficiency"? The efficiency you gain here is peanuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to have the method to return a value. That can be done like this:

```
public double convertYourself(double x) {
    System.out.println("How many are you buying?");
    double currency = in.nextDouble();
    double convert = currency * x;

    return convert;
}

//To call it:
double valueReturned = convertYourself(gemValue);
```

So, you would have to change the method return value from `void` to `double`, and use the `return` keyword to return the value you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a return type instead of `void` for a method.
The return value must then be returned via `return {value}`.

```java
//   return type
//      \/
public double convertYourself (double x) {
  double convert = /* convert */;
  return convert;
}
```

After that you can store the output in a variable:

```java
double result = convertYourself (/* x */);
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific with the coding part:

```
public class TestCode {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static double gemValue = 0.01;
    public static double goldValue = 0.000004;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TestCode test = new TestCode(); ... you do not need this as the both methods are inside the same class. Make the convertYourself method as *static*. 
        double gemValueConverted = convertYourself(gemValue); // call it without the object 
        double goldValueConverted = convertYourself(goldValue);

        double sum = gemValueConverted + goldValueConverted;
        System.out.println("The total value of this bundle is :" + sum);
    }

    public static double convertYourself(double x) { // made the method static and added return type as double
        System.out.println("How many are you buying?");
        double currency = in.nextDouble();
        double convert = currency * x;
        System.out.println("The true value of this is: " + convert);
        return convert;
    }
}
```